# How to indicate 'X' simply means 'Y'

Tags: sentence-structure

How a native speaker would say or write: 'X' simply means 'Y'?

(In my language there is one single structure for both cases of written English and spoken English.)

I have found several cases, but I don't know which one is written and which one can be used in spoken English and which one is used in both cases:

> - 1) **In plain terms** cancer is a type of disease where cells grow out of control, divide and invade other tissues.
> - 2) **In plain language** cancer is a type of disease where cells grow out of control, divide and invade other tissues.
> - 3) **Simply put** cancer is a type of disease where cells grow out of control, divide and invade other tissues.
> - 4) **Simply cancer is** a type of disease where cells grow out of control, divide and invade other tissues.

Comment: I would say 'basically' or 'in simple terms'. 3 and 4 definitely sound the best

Comment: @akkatracker - I wouldn't use "simply" at the beginning of a sentence before a noun like that, because used that way, it means something like "only".  It would sound more fluent to say "Cancer is simply..." rather than "Simply cancer is..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between written and spoken English.  Some structures might be more formal, and therefore used more often in writing, and some less formal, and therefore used more often in casual conversation, but there is no [hard and fast](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+hard+and+fast+rules) rule about written vs. spoken forms.

---

As for these phrases, did you try looking these up in Google Books and seeing how people use them?  For example, here's [**simply put**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22simply+put%22#q=%22simply+put%22&tbm=bks&tbs=bkt:m):

> [Simply put, calcium allows the muscle to expand and magnesium is required for the muscle to contract.](https://books.google.com/books?id=kdwDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22simply%20put%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6tuLilIjSAhXI8CYKHVBkCaYQ6AEINjAH#v=onepage&q=%22simply%20put%22&f=false)
>
> [Simply put, agents work to ensure buyers' future happiness.](https://books.google.com/books?id=4EstCRo-wBsC&pg=RA1-PA115&dq=%22simply%20put%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4u_C1lojSAhWJ3SYKHS5AC6c4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22simply%20put%22&f=false)

This looks like what you want: "**Simply put**, X is (or does) Y."   And here's [**in plain language**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+plain+language%22#q=%22in+plain+language%22&tbm=bks&tbs=bkt:m):

> [We must have statutes drafted in plain language...](https://books.google.com/books?id=ACI4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA319&dq=%22in%20plain%20language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNyO_dlojSAhUKOSYKHbSyBlQQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20plain%20language%22&f=false)
>
> [A mine of valuable information explaining in plain language the How and Why of every operation.](https://books.google.com/books?id=uN8DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA19&dq=%22in%20plain%20language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2wfH2lojSAhVFeSYKHZM6D5k4FBDoAQg5MAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20plain%20language%22&f=false)

You can see that they're used very differently.  **Simply** is also used at the beginning of a sentence, but only before a verb, not a noun, because it means essentially "only":

> [Simply double click on the current track's name...](https://books.google.com/books?id=c-sDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22simply%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij57S6l4jSAhWFQCYKHZgkCWk4FBDoAQghMAI#v=onepage&q=%22simply%22&f=false)
>
> [Simply giving any kind of educational institution the title of university will not solve a great deal.
>   ...
>   Remember, too, that the members of these outside bodies are, in the main, university academics considering their own specialities, and not **simply** individuals pushing for their alma mater.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_4SXKOBgJ_kC&pg=PA48&dq=%22simply%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij57S6l4jSAhWFQCYKHZgkCWk4FBDoAQg5MAg#v=onepage&q=%22simply%22&f=false)

**In plain terms** is also OK:

> [Partly because of the repositioning, Horchow's "price points" were too high— in plain terms, some merchandise was too expensive.](https://books.google.com/books?id=hSsEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22in%20plain%20terms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ_4n0mIjSAhXDLSYKHfM_AF8Q6AEIOjAI#v=onepage&q=%22in%20plain%20terms%22&f=false)
>
> [In plain terms, the organization cannot get a fair hearing in the press or on television.](https://books.google.com/books?id=MyvwzW2QW8UC&pg=PA16&dq=%22in%20plain%20terms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxouuOmYjSAhVG5CYKHQPeB_Q4ChDoAQg1MAc#v=onepage&q=%22in%20plain%20terms%22&f=false)

---

Other phrases you might use are [**to put it simply**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22simply%20put%22#tbs=bkt:m&tbm=bks&q=%22to%20put%20it%20simply%22) or [**to put it in simple terms**.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22simply%20put%22#q=%22to%20put%20it%20in%20simple%20terms%22&tbm=bks&tbas=0)  Note that any phrase you use like this at the beginning of the sentence or clause should have a comma after it.

Comment: Hence all my sentences sounds natural in English and there is no any difference in formality degree and also they all mean the same @stangdon. Do you confirm it? :)

Comment: They're all OK except for #4, which I would not use, for the reasons I explained.  *Simply put* is maybe a little more formal than the others.

Comment: Just for making sure, do you mean "Cancer **simply** is..." means "Cancer **only** is..."  @Stangdon?

Comment: Correct.  I wouldn't really use **simply**, for exactly that reason.